# Google Colab read file from Google Drive Sync Folder

Tags: google-colaboratory

I just uploaded gigabytes of photos to google drive using Google Backup and Sync(https://www.google.com/intl/en_as/drive/download/backup-and-sync/). But I cannot reach those file from Google Colab since it can only display files in "My Drive" but not /drive/Computer/MY Mac Book Pro/Files/... And I can not move those files to "My Drive", it saids server error. I am using free spaces account from G-suit.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similliar issue.. I dont know if this is what made it work for me, but try closing the back up and sync program